# React Copy Array using Spread Operator Not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I am workng with react js state i have a fake array in my state name **jObj** i am copying it using spread operator into variable **copy** and after that updating **jObj** using function **expandArray** don't know why **copy** variable updating
here is my both functions

```
 fakeMethod=()=>{
        let  jObj=[];
        jObj[0]=[];
        jObj[0]['id']=1;
        jObj[0]["title"]="parent Object";
        jObj[0]['parentId']=[];
        jObj[0]['options']=[];
        jObj[0]['options'][0]=[];
        jObj[0]['options'][0]['name']="Yes";
        jObj[0]['options'][0]['value']="yes";
        jObj[0]['options'][0]['id']=3;
        jObj[0]['options'][1]=[];
        jObj[0]['options'][1]['name']="No";
        jObj[0]['options'][1]['value']="no";
        jObj[0]['options'][1]['id']=4;
        jObj[1]=[];
        jObj[1]['id']=1;
        jObj[1]["title"]="child Object";
        jObj[1]['parentId']=[3,4];
        jObj[1]['options']=[];

        const copy=[...jObj]
        jObj=this.expandArray(jObj);
        console.log("This is orignal object")
        console.log(jObj);
        console.log("This is copy object")
        console.log(copy)
        return ""
    }
    expandArray=(input)=>{
        let result = input.map(a => a.id);
        var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, result);
        var newArr = [];
        for (var i in input) {
            var first = true;
            let objCopy = Object.assign({}, input[i].parentId);
            input[i]=Object.assign(input[i],{"initObjectPos":i});
            if(input[i].parentId.length == 0){
                input[i].parentId="";
            }
            for (var x in objCopy) {
                var y = input[i];

                if (!first) {
                    y = Object.assign({}, y);
                    max_of_array++;
                    y.id = max_of_array.toString();
                    newArr.push(y);
                }
                y.parentId = objCopy[x];
                first = false;
            }
        }
        var output = input.concat(newArr);
        return output;
    }
```

please help me about where i am wrong i think i am copying array correctly and something is wrong inside expand array function
Thanks Much!!

Answer (score 2):

The spread operator will not create a deep clone of your Object.
Since some of your object's properties are objects themselves, their copy will be passed by reference. If you will change one of their attributes, your first Object will be changed again.
The easiest way to avoid this is to you use lodash's cloneDeep method.
[Lodash Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)

```
const copy=cloneDeep(jObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you're creating an empty array, not an array of objects in the fakeMethod(). if you look into the following code, you'll find the mistake while creating jObj[0], jObj[1], jObj[0]['options'][0];

```
    let  jObj=[];
    jObj[0]={};
    jObj[0]['id']=1;
    jObj[0]["title"]="parent Object";
    jObj[0]['parentId']=[];
    jObj[0]['options']=[];
    jObj[0]['options'][0]={};
    jObj[0]['options'][0]['name']="Yes";
    jObj[0]['options'][0]['value']="yes";
    jObj[0]['options'][0]['id']=3;
    jObj[0]['options'][1]={};
    jObj[0]['options'][1]['name']="No";
    jObj[0]['options'][1]['value']="no";
    jObj[0]['options'][1]['id']=4;
    jObj[1]={};
    jObj[1]['id']=1;
    jObj[1]["title"]="child Object";
    jObj[1]['parentId']=[3,4];
    jObj[1]['options']=[];
```

Comment: when using you code getting same result you can put you code in my code and check result

Answer (score 1):

**As of 2024** probably the best method is to use the native structuredClone() method introduced in ES2019

This will copy your array without any references

So instead of:

```
const copy=[...jObj]
```

Use:

```
const copy=structuredClone(jObj)
```

More information and a polyfill for older browsers can be on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/22669647) SO answer