# I have 2 states, but both are updating even though I only setState one of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem**

using React, I have a meal, which has an array of ingredients

`const [meal, setMeal] = useState()`

```
    meal = {
      foo: ,
      bar: ,
      ingredients: [
        id:
        name:
      ]
    }
```

I also need to edit the ingredients name, so I have a different state to track it. I have used the spread operator on this.

`[changeIngredients, setChangeIngredients] = useState();`
// in a separate useEffect
`setChangeIngredients([...meal.ingredients])`

The problem starts when I update `changeIngredients` as such

```
  handleEdit = (e) => {
    let temp = [...changeIngredients];
    temp[e.positionOfArray].name = Number(e.target.value);
    setChangeIngredients(temp);
  };
```

I find that `meal.ingredients` is also updated, and as such can't do a comparison to see if anything changed.

I previously tried using setChangeIngredients with the response.data from an API call, but the results were the same.

`setMeal(response.data)`
`setChangeIngredients([...response.data.ingredients])`

---

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Hi there :) Could you produce a working example on  `codesandbox`

Comment: Try this: `setChangeIngredients(prevState => ({...prevState, ...temp}))`

Comment: more interested to see your useEffect

Comment: Thanks for the help all. Yi Zhou's answer was the solution. I failed to take into account that the array had more objects in it that I had to clone.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are mutate on the same object, this `setChangeIngredients([...meal.ingredients])` each object inside are still pointing to the same reference of `ingredients`

Bascially your need clone a copy of `meal.ingredients` first on your inital `setChangeIngredients`

```
const sourceArray = meal.ingredients;
const clonedArray = sourceArray.map(item => ({...item}));
setChangeIngredients(clonedArray)
```

For more info check here about immutable https://dev.to/antonio_pangall/best-practices-to-keep-objects-and-arrays-immutable-in-javascript-3nmm

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the problem. I kept trying to use spread on the different variables but failed to take into account that the array is filled with objects too.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63688454/10779129), spread operator only makes a shallow copy. It only clones  main object ... The copy of the properties will still be pass by reference.